# gitlab credentials for specific user

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem figuring out how I can add credentials for a deploy job in gitlab in a way that only a certain user or usergroup gets access to them.

So what I want to do is the following. I have a gitlab instance with a gitlab-ci configuration that adds a manually activated job to deploy my code. The deploy job runs in a docker image and deploys via fabric to a server. This fabric call now needs an ssh private key to log into the server to deploy onto. That still wouldn't prevent anyone from clicking on this manual job but at least it would fail because of the missing credentials.

I now added the ssh private key as a secret variable. But unfortunately, this secret variable is visible to everyone who can trigger the build. Which would be all developers. Because I, of course, want them to be able to trigger the build jobs. I just don't want them to be able to trigger the deploy job. And I, of course, don't want them to be able to access the ssh key. E.g. through checking in "echo $SECRET_VARIBLE". So in my ideal world, I would be able to add a secret variable only to my account with is only set if I am the person who triggers the job.

Comment: This isn't possible and you're pushing the limitations of Gitlab here. I'd suggest you look at acquiring the key another way, perhaps using Hashicorp's Vault SSH backend.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand why this would push any limits. All I want is to be able to store some information only available to the gitlab-runner when it is my account who triggered the build. E.g. on my profile I would have a section with variables where I could add a credential and only when I build this variable is added.