# Gitlab CI Secrets at user level for deployment login

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, artifactory, conan

We have a Gitlab Project with multiple developers, and the repo itself is a conan Project.

When creating a release tag, I want to setup a **pipeline which creates the conan package** and then uploads it to artifactory. Uploading to the Artifactory requires a **username and password login**. This is similar to many other deployment jobs where a user+pass authentication is required.

I already found a solution to define secret variables for the project (project level) and use a single account for the whole project to upload to artifactory. This is security-wise an issue, as we want to know who uploaded the conan package, i.e., which user.

Is it somehow in Gitlab possible to define **secrets on the user level**?
I.e., if `User1` creates the tag and has his own Artifactory Account User+Pass secrets set up, the pipeline successfuly pushes the conan package.
If now `User2` creates a tag but did not setup secrets, the push should fail.

---

The following Gitlab issue is a similar description of the problem, but does not contain any solution:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15815

Also related: [gitlab credentials for specific user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426333/gitlab-credentials-for-specific-user) (but handles a shared secret with specific user access).

Answer (score 0):

CI secrets are currently only project level, but you might be able to do something similar with one of the predefined env variables. There are four variables that hold info about the Gitlab user who started the pipeline (either by trigger, schedule, push, etc). `$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL`, `$GITLAB_USER_ID`, `$GITLAB_USER_LOGIN`, `$GITLAB_USER_NAME`. Then, in your projects secret variables, you can store credentials for each of your users, and in your job grab the correct one based on the USER variables.

Comment: Thank you for the Idea! This approach still has the issue that every user needs to set up his credentials for every project. In addition, it would be possible to extract another user's credentials via a malicious pipeline run (e.g. POST request to a custom server)